# Can't update state in React Context using function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I currently have two contexts - GalleryContext & AdminContext

In AdminContext, whenever I fire off handleSendImage(), I am trying to call a function (getGallery()) from GalleryContext which updates the gallery state in GalleryContext.

However, I am receiving this error:
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): this.setState is not a function

Could anyone please advise me on how to fix this? Much appreciated in advance!

Here's my code:

GalleryContext:

```
class GalleryProvider extends Component {
  state = {
    gallery: []
  };
  getGallery() {
    let database = firebase
      .database()
      .ref("/gallery/")
      .once("value")
      .then(images => {
        console.log(images.val());
        this.setState(
          {
            gallery: images.val()
          },
          () => {}
        );
      });
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getGallery();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <GalleryContext.Provider
        value={{
          ...this.state,
          getGallery: this.getGallery
        }}>
        {this.props.children}
      </GalleryContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

AdminContext.js

```
class AdminProvider extends Component {
  static contextType = GalleryContext;
  state = {
    upload_image: null,
    gallery_title: null,
    gallery_description: null,
    gallery_filename: null,
    progress: null
  };
  handleSendImage = (event, gallery, user) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { upload_image } = this.state;
    firebase
      .storage()
      .ref(`images/${upload_image.name}`)
      .put(upload_image)
      .on(
        "state_changed",
        snapshot => {
          // progrss function ....
          const progress = Math.round(
            (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
          );
          this.setState({
            progress
          });
        },
        error => {
          // error function ....
          console.log(error);
        },
        () => {
          // complete function ....
          firebase
            .storage()
            .ref("images")
            .child(upload_image.name)
            .getDownloadURL()
            .then(url => {
              const newImage = {
                description: this.state.gallery_description,
                download_url: url,
                file_name: this.state.gallery_filename,
                id: gallery.length,
                uploader_uid: user.uid
              };
              firebase
                .database()
                .ref("/gallery/")
                .child(gallery.length)
                .set(newImage)
                .then(() => {
                  this.context.getGallery();
                })
                .catch(error => {
                  console.log(error);
                });
            });
        }
      );
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <AdminContext.Provider
        value={{
          ...this.state
          handleSendImage: this.handleSendImage
        }}>
        {this.props.children}
      </AdminContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you might need to bind `this` to your `getGallery` method inside your class constructor: `this.getGallery = this.getGallery.bind(this)`... Or better yet change `getGallery(){}` to `getGallery = () => {}`. That way you dont need to do the bind

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using states, you would need a constructor for your class component and need to bind your methods within the constructor. I suggest you to try the following code:

```
class AdminProvider extends Component {

  static contextType = GalleryContext;
  constructor(props) { 
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    upload_image: null,
    gallery_title: null,
    gallery_description: null,
    gallery_filename: null,
    progress: null
  };
  this.handleSendImage = this.handleSendImage.bind(this);
  }
  handleSendImage = (event, gallery, user) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { upload_image } = this.state;
    firebase
      .storage()
      .ref(`images/${upload_image.name}`)
      .put(upload_image)
      .on(
        "state_changed",
        snapshot => {
          // progrss function ....
          const progress = Math.round(
            (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
          );
          this.setState({
            progress
          });
        },
        error => {
          // error function ....
          console.log(error);
        },
        () => {
          // complete function ....
          firebase
            .storage()
            .ref("images")
            .child(upload_image.name)
            .getDownloadURL()
            .then(url => {
              const newImage = {
                description: this.state.gallery_description,
                download_url: url,
                file_name: this.state.gallery_filename,
                id: gallery.length,
                uploader_uid: user.uid
              };
              firebase
                .database()
                .ref("/gallery/")
                .child(gallery.length)
                .set(newImage)
                .then(() => {
                  this.context.getGallery();
                })
                .catch(error => {
                  console.log(error);
                });
            });
        }
      );
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <AdminContext.Provider
        value={{
          ...this.state
          handleSendImage: this.handleSendImage
        }}>
        {this.props.children}
      </AdminContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Similarly:

```
    class GalleryProvider extends Component {
  constructor(props) { 
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    gallery: []
  };
  this.getGallery = this.getGallery.bind(this);
  }
  getGallery() {
    let database = firebase
      .database()
      .ref("/gallery/")
      .once("value")
      .then(images => {
        console.log(images.val());
        this.setState(
          {
            gallery: images.val()
          },
          () => {}
        );
      });
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getGallery();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <GalleryContext.Provider
        value={{
          ...this.state,
          getGallery: this.getGallery
        }}>
        {this.props.children}
      </GalleryContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you could use React Hooks inside functional components. Hope this solves your problem.

I would suggest you to read [React's documentation on Constructor](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor) for more information.